# How can I retrieve Picklist Values of a Support Process in APEX?

Tags: apex

I have one Case Record Type which has a Support Process. How can I specifically get those Support Process picklist values via Apex?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: see https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gNpLAAU for how to get picklist values for a recordtype